# matlab gui - draw points and lines on image

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to do in matlab, GUI that the the user enters points and connection between them. he also enters a map photo(png image) and scale for the axes(axe x will be from 0 to scale).
At the end(after he enters all the input) I want to show the user the image with all the nodes and connection on it.

I have 5 matlab files - screen1.m, screen2.m, screen3.m, screen4.m, globalParams.m

in globalParams I have global params so I can use them from screen GUI to screen GUI. in screen1 the user enters the number of nodes(for example 5), and also he enters the map. when he press the Next button the callback function calls "`screen2();`". in screen2.m the user enters the (x,y) coordiante and when he press the Next button the callback function calls "`screen3();`".
in screen3 the user update all the connections between all the nodes. when finishes he press the Finish button and the callback function calls "`screen4`". in screen4 I added in the GUI axes and there I did "`imshow`"..
**but the real thing that I want to do is to change the axes to be from 0 to scale(instead of 0 to 1), I want also to put the image(I did it with imshow), and the last and the most important thing I want to put on the image is the nodes and the lines between them(if the user add connection between node i to node j so in the image will be a line between them. maybe to put the lines and the nodes with diffrent colors so we can distinguish the lines and the nodes)**
in screen4 we have: **xNodes** and **yNodes**- 2 arrays for nodes "x" and "y" axes.((xNodes(1),yNodes(1) is node1 place). Also we have **Scale** and **fullPathName** for the image name. we have also hopsMatrix it's 2D array- if hopsMatrix(i,j)=1 there is a connection between i to j.

some code:

in screen1, the upload image and numOfNodes and scale:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

global fullPathName;
[fileName pathName] = uigetfile({'*.png'},'File Selector');
fullPathName = strcat(pathName, fileName);
imshow(fullPathName);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

global numOfNodes;
global scale;
scale = str2num(get(handles.edit1, 'string'));
numOfNodes = str2num(get(handles.edit2, 'string'));
```

in screen4, where I have all the inputs and I want to put the nodes in the map(I dont know how to do it, so for now this is the code):

```
% --- Executes just before screen4 is made visible.
function screen4_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to screen4 (see VARARGIN)

global fullPathName;
global xNodes;
global yNodes;
global scale;
global hopsMatrix;
img = imread(fullPathName);
imshow(fullPathName);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution someone gave me.. I'll share it

```
% --- Executes just before screen4 is made visible.
function screen4_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to screen4 (see VARARGIN)

global fullPathName;
imshow(fullPathName);
global xNodes;
global yNodes;
global scale;
global hopsMatrix;

x_original=get(handles.axes1,'xlim');
y_original=get(handles.axes1,'ylim');
min_lim=min(x_original(2),y_original(2));
max_lim=max(x_original(1),y_original(1));
xlim([max_lim,min_lim])
ylim([max_lim,min_lim])
dist=min_lim-max_lim;
set(handles.axes1)
hold on
plot((xNodes(:,1))*dist/scale+x_original(1),min_lim+y_original(1)-(yNodes(:,1))*dist/scale,'rx','markersize',8,'linewidth',2)
[row,col] = find(hopsMatrix);
for i=1:length(row)
    plot((xNodes([row(i),1;col(i),1]))*dist/scale+x_original(1),min_lim+y_original(1)-(yNodes([row(i),1;col(i),1]))*dist/scale,'k','linewidth',2)

end
```